# SQL relative percentage for each country

Tags: sql, percentage

I have a table: maps_query like below:

```
CREATE TABLE maps_query 
(
    id           int 
    day          varchar
    search_query varchar
    country      varchar
    query_score  int
)
```

The question is to output the relative percentage of queries for maps_query for each country.

Desired output is like below:

```
country     pct
----------------
CA          0.13
FR          0.45
GB          0.21
```

I don't quite understand what relative percentage is here but I assumed it's asking to output  (a country's search_query counts/ all search_query for all countries)?

Would something like the following work?

```
Select 
    country, 
    (sum(search_query) / sum(search_query) over () * 100) pct
From 
    map_search
Group by 
    country
```

Comment: You should always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using. There are DBMS out there that apply kindergarten math:  7 / 2 = 3, rather than 7 / 2 = 3.5 for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it.  Here's your SQL adjusted slightly:

```
SELECT country
     , SUM(query_score) / (SUM(SUM(query_score)) OVER ()) AS pct
     , SUM(query_score)
     , SUM(SUM(query_score)) OVER ()
  FROM map_search
 GROUP BY country
;
```

**The result, using some test data:**

```
+---------+--------+------------------+-------------------------------+
| country | pct    | SUM(query_score) | SUM(SUM(query_score)) OVER () |
+---------+--------+------------------+-------------------------------+
| C1      | 0.5323 |             3300 |                          6200 |
| C2      | 0.4677 |             2900 |                          6200 |
+---------+--------+------------------+-------------------------------+
```

`search_query` wasn't a numeric type.  I think you meant `query_score`.

No need to multiply by 100, if your expected result is not a percent, but just the fraction between 0 and 1.

Your use of a window function wasn't quite valid, since you tried to `SUM OVER` a non-aggregate (expression not functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY` terms).

I resolved that by using SUM(query_score) as the expression to use in the window function argument.

Answer (score 2):

First compute total search query and then use that total to get relative percentage for each country.

```
with total as
           ( select sum(search_query) as total
           from maps_query)

select country,
       search_query / total.total 
       from maps_query,total
```

Comment: Please don't use comma-separated joins. They have been made redundant in 1992. If you want a cross join then use `from maps_query cross join total`. I prefer the OP's approach, though. This is an adequate task for a window function. You don't explain why you suggest not to use it and recommend a different approach instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `search_query` seems to be a query string. You cannot sum it, it's not a number. What you probably want to do is *count* queries per country.

Apart from this your query looks quite fine, but if `search_query` really were a number to add up then you'd have to calculate the sum and the sum of the sums: `sum(search_query) / sum(sum(search_query)) over ()`.

Here is your query corrected:

```
Select 
    country, 
    (count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () * 100) as pct
From 
    map_search
Group by 
    country 
Order by 
    country;
```